# Can I constrain a module's type to be a tuple?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

```
module type S = sig
       type 'a t
end

module A = struct
       type 'a t  = 'a list
end

module B = struct
       type ('a,'b) t  = ('a * 'b) list
end

module Make (P : S) = struct
       type 'a t = 'a P.t
end

module Single = struct
       include Make (A)
end

module Tuple = struct
       include Make (B)
end
```

Basically, I want to reuse the make functor, except for in Tuple, force the type to be a tuple. Is this possible?

I think the module type S is messing it up, which is giving me the error: They have different arities. Maybe it is possible to get this working using first class modules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish? If you forget about functors for a second you will see that your module `B` cannot satisfy the signature `S`. For example:

```
module B1 = (B : S)
```

Will give you the same error. The problem here is that your type `t` in your singature `S` only accepts 1 type variable. You cannot apply this signature to a module with type `t` with 2 type variables.

Comment: Right. What I'm trying to accomplish is have both Single and Tuple have mostly the same interface and implementation. The only differences would be:

1. Tuple's polymorphic type should be a tuple.
2. The differences in implementation can be split off into the modules A and B (where B handles the tuple version).

I think it would work if I duplicate the Make module for both Single and Tuple so that I don't introduce S. Having two modules that are basically the same seems undesirable though.

Comment: Please post an example of how you are using these modules. That is the easiest way to help you. One restriction that you can do is make the tuple contain elements of the same type `type 'a t = 'a * 'a list`